# Are Len(cell.Value) = 0 and cell.Value = "" equivalent in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

When evaluating the value of a cell in a worksheet in Excel, is the following statement true?

If and only if **`Len(cell.Value) = 0`**, then **`cell.Value = "".`**

This would imply that it is safe to check that there are zero characters in a cell instead of comparing the cell value to an empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they do the same thing.

However, I would advise that you use the `IsEmpty` function to check for empty cells. If you enter a single quote into a cell `'` both the `len` check and the `=""` check will both state the the cell is empty.  When in actual fact it isn't.

`IsEmpty` will return false in this scenario.

And it's also a little easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, that's good to know. Although outside the scope of my question, only caution would be that when using the Trim function and thus evaluating the value of the cell as a string, IsEmpty will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure your statement is true. I've been using it for quite a while and never had an issue with that assumption

My two cents : I'm not sure you gain a lot of performance from the trick, and it maybe easier for other people to understand the meaning of `cell.Value = ""` than `Len(cell.Value) = 0`

Comment: I think you are right. I evaluated two cells 500000 times with a loop, and cell.Value = "" took 48 seconds while Len(cell.Value) = 0 took 49 seconds.

Comment: I think the lack of difference is largely because the time to read the value from the cell is much greater than the time taken to do the comparison/length check... if you check with string variables you should see that using 'Len()=0' is actually around twice the speed of '=""'.

Comment: Good point Simon. I evaluated five strings, four of them 10-15 characters in length and one empty one, 50000000 times, and the execution times were 26 seconds for string = "" and 17 seconds for Len(string) = 0.